# Return a non-200 Http Status from a .net lambda - without an API Gateway

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, http-status-codes

I'm trying to return other http status codes from .net using amazon.lambda.core - I tried this as a handler:

```cs
    public async Task<string> Handler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(0);
        throw new AmazonLambdaException(Json.Serialize(new { error = "Your specific error message" }), ErrorType.Sender,
            "Bad Request", "abc", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

But when I call it from for instance a python client app - I get:

response =

```json
 {'RequestId': 'xxx', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Thu, 07 Sep 2023 07:29:09 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '1053', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxx', 'x-amz-function-error': 'Unhandled', 'x-amzn-remapped-content-length': '0', 'x-amz-executed-version': '$LATEST', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'root=xxx;sampled=1;lineage=xxx:0'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'StatusCode': 200, 'FunctionError': 'Unhandled', 'ExecutedVersion': '$LATEST', 'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x0000021A6B813100>}
```

The key thing I want to change is that statuscode 200 - is it possible?

Note - there is no api gateway involved in this picture - just one thing making a direct http call to a lambda function (although in this case I'm calling it from boto3)

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is the call executed OK from the clients perspective but fails internally and you don't actually return anything! You just throw an error inside the Lambda which runs in a tiny container.

Looking at the documentation [APIGatewayProxyResponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html) they return this:

```
var response = new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Body = "Hello AWS Serverless",
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type",
"text/plain" } }
            };
            
            return response;
    }
```

So you could do something like this:

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> Handler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
    if (1 == 1) 
    {
        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = 400,
            Body = "Something Bad happened with the request",
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "application/json" } }
        };
    }
}
```

You should get some hints (ie that Exception you've been throwing) in the CloudWatch logs for the Lambda.

**Update**

If there is no API GW involved (which I didn't fully note at first) and you're returning a `string`, then just do what Python or Node do:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 400,
        'body': json.dumps('BadRequest')
    }
```

[image]

The Console is a little misleading, see how it's failed here and that doesn't return a 400. The status display only has two states: Successful and Failed. With an API GW HTTP concepts come more into play.

[image]

Comment: yeah - unfortunately - didn't work it all - it just comes out with a payload of that serialized apigatewayproxyresponse...   but a status code of 200.  NOTE - I'm calling the lambda directly - not using an api gateway.   An api gateway is not an option in this case

Comment: I had a go and I think I understand the issue - calling the Lambda from another service you want to know if it failed, To answer your original question its not possible to change the statuscode from 200 without an API GW, you have to parse the text/json response as per the screenshot . Not the ideal solution.

Comment: yeah - unfortunately - the problem is - we control the lambda - but we _don't_ control the consumer - they are just doing a direct lambda call to us - and they are always going "oh you succeeded?"